# Eigen alignment issues

Tags: c++11, eigen, memory-alignment, eigen3

Do the memory alignment issues with Eigen listed in the [documentation](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__DenseMatrixManipulation__Alignement.html) still apply with C++11? It seems that C++11 can already take care of properly aligning objects on the stack and on the heap, with `alignas` and `std::allocator` which supports alignment.

Comment: Are you talking about the part of the documentation that references a gcc bug?

Comment: Also that you can't pass Eigen object by value, need use a custom allocator for container, a spezialized `std::vector`, and the macro to overload `operator new` in classes that contain Eigen objects. Because in C++11 memory alignment seems to be supported for for stack and heap memory.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, the alignment issues are still present in C++11. The `alignas` specifier has no effect on dynamic allocations, which can thus still cause misalignments resulting in assertions thrown by Eigen.

You will have to continue to use the facilities Eigen provides for aligned allocation, such as `EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW` for allocating objects or `Eigen::aligned_allocator<T>` for aligning containers.

Answer (score 1):

While the question is about C++11 specifically, it is worth noting that a combination of the upcoming Eigen version 3.4 with a C++17 compliant compiler will free us from the need to use `EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW` and `Eigen::aligned_allocator<T>`. The former macro is actually even empty then. This is possible by a new form of `operator new` that is specifically designed to support overalignment.